# issues installing .pkg file osx through installer

Tags: macos, installer

I have a .pkg which needs to be installed. This is basically for Updating my app having multiple components.
The pkg contains Agent , Daemon and a helper. In Post script am starting the Agent through Sudo $USER launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgent/myApp.plist.
I want to automate the installation of pkg.
Installer command line is being used to install this pkg.
This works fine when I run the app from Xcode and pkg is cleanly installed.

But when I am not running my app from debug mode in Xcode and my app is installed and I try to install the pkg with help of helper tool(running as root) , installer command is executing. 
But the problem is with the loading of Agent. The Agent never gets started.

But when I use Su command instead of SUDO command to load Agent that is using
   su -l $USER -c "/bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/myApp.plist" ,
the Agent gets started.

But I am having issues with use of SU wherein helper tool installation fails subsequently.

So 
1. why is SUDO command failing and not able to load the Agent when it is being run from a tool running as root.(This tool was started by daemon) .

2. If I load the Agent through SU , my helper tool installation fails.

**Update**::::
I was able to start the Agent. But the problem persists because Helper tool installation fails which tries to Authenticate. Here is the authentication code:                                                          AuthorizationRef authRef = NULL;
    AuthorizationItem authItem = { kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper, 0, NULL, 0 };
    AuthorizationRights authRights = { 1, &authItem };
    AuthorizationFlags flags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

```
OSStatus status=AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authRef);
if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess) 
{
    DLog(@"Failed to create AuthorizationRef, return code %i", status);
}
else
{
    result = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (__bridge CFStringRef)label, authRef, &outError);
    if (!result && error)
    {
        *error = (__bridge NSError *)(outError);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61901/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-launchagent-as-another-user), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106638/starting-stopping-a-launchd-agent-for-all-users-with-gui-sessions), [here](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2011-January/000890.html), and [here](https://github.com/MagerValp/Scripted-Mac-Package-Creation/blob/master/scripts/postinstall).

Comment: Edited the Question to Include Authentication of Helper tool installation which is failing after Agent was started..